# Getting Right position of MasterDetailPage Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a custom hamburger with its own animation. I wanted to know if there was a way of attaching it to the rightmost side of the MasterDetailPage's sliding menu so that it moves when it is pressed? Is there any way to get that value or at least a value to do with the animation of that page so that I can translate it accordingly

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the master page at the right side?

Comment: No. I want to display a view on the right side of the sliding menu.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is accomplished through using the "RotateYTo" method and it works also on MasterDetailPage.

Try the following in your MasterDetailPage initiation.

```
        this.RotateYTo(180);
        this.Master.RotateYTo(180);
        this.Details.RotateYTo(180);
```

Edit:

It looks like I got your question all in a wrong way.

Anyways. If you need something to appear right next to the Master Page you should add it on the left side of the Detail page. The Master page also takes a width parameter which you can manipulate.

Comment: I'm Translating it's X value not the Y and definitely not rotating it. I'm trying to keep an image view attached to the rightside of the masterdetailpage so that when the hamburger image view is pressed, it moves with the masterdetailpage...